# No such module 'Alamofire' - Xcode 12

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, alamofire, swifty-json

I'm trying to import Alamofire to a Swift 5 Xcode project (Xcode 12, iOS 14.4) but I'm getting the 'No such module'Alamofire'' error message.

The Cocoapods for the latest Alamofire and SwiftyJSON versions, which I added at the same time, both appear to have installed correctly and 'Import SwiftyJSON' is not throwing up the same error in Xcode.

Any ideas what is going on with this? Has Alamofire been replaced?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Can you share your Podfile?

Comment: its fixed. no idea how, I made no changes. I had tried a few clean builds which failed, left it for a while, came back to it and it seems to be ok on reopening xcode. I had previously  restarted xcode a few time with no success.... one of the many quirks of xcode I guess...

Answer (score 0):

It just seemed to sort itself out without any changes after numerous attempts at a clean build and closing and reopening xcode - weird